# Media Queries Display:none

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My name is Jeffrey and I just started creating websites. Now as I'm very new I do have little HTML/CSS knowlegde, but I have almost zero knowledge when it comes to media queries and I'm hoping someone can help me out as I can't seem to fix this myself...

I have a div with logo and text menu. As I'm trying to build this website for mobile as well, I'd like to remove the logo and show the menu only. The problem is that the menu won't get centered and that my container stays too small...

```css
body{margin:0;font-family:'Titillium Web';}
a:hover{color:#60a642;}
a{color:#000;text-decoration:none;} 
@media screen and (max-width:1155px) {
 #containerlogomenu {width:60% !important;}
    #logo {padding:0px; margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:761px) {
 #containerlogomenu {width:100%; padding:0px;}
    #logo {display:none;padding:0px; margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;}
 #menu {width:100%;}
}

 
#top{
 width:100%;
 height:140px;
 background-color:#f2f2f2;}

 #containerlogomenu{
  padding:20px;
  width:40%;}
  
 #logo{
  float:left;
  padding-left:50px;
  padding-right:50px;
  width:60px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#F00;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;}
  
 #menu{
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:19px;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:110px;
  width:65%;
  float:right;
  color:#000;}
```

```html
<div id="top" align="center">
 <div id="containerlogomenu" align="center">
 
     <div id="logo"></div>
        
     <div id="menu"> 
         <a href="#">HOME</a> | 
            <a href="#step1">STEP 1</a> | 
            <a href="#step2">STEP 2</a> | 
          <a href="#step3">STEP 3</a></div>
         
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone is able to help me out! Anyway very much appreciated for your time and efforts in advance!

Comment: only home Link None or All link none in mobile view ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the media queries BELOW all the other CSS rules, otherwise they will be overridden by the regular rules.

Comment: So simple... yet I had no clue what to look for... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**JsFiddle Example** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vt976asr/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
body{margin:0;font-family:'Titillium Web';}
a:hover{color:#60a642;}
a{color:#000;text-decoration:none;} 
@media screen and (max-width:1155px) {
#containerlogomenu {width:60% !important;}
#logo {padding:0px; margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:761px) {
#containerlogomenu {width:100% !important; padding:0px;}
#logo {display:none;padding:0px; margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}
#menu {width:100%}
  .HomeLink
  {
display:none;
  }
}


#top{
width:100%;
height:140px;
background-color:#f2f2f2;}

#containerlogomenu{
 padding:20px;
 width:40%;}
 
#logo{
 float:left;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding-right:50px;
 width:60px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#F00;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;}
 
#menu{
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:19px;      
 line-height:110px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 color:#000;}
```

```html
<div id="top" align="center">
 <div id="containerlogomenu" align="center">
 
     <div id="logo"></div>
        
     <div id="menu"> 
         <a href="#" class="HomeLink">HOME</a> | 
            <a href="#step1">STEP 1</a> | 
            <a href="#step2">STEP 2</a> | 
          <a href="#step3">STEP 3</a></div>
         
  </div>
</div>
```